# Is there any alternative for Hyper V WMI GuestIntrinsicExchangeItems or GuestExchangeItems for virtualbox and vmware

Tags: c#, virtualbox, vmware, hyper-v, hypervisor

GuestIntrinsicExchangeItems and GuestExchangeItems are WMI properties of [KvpExchangeComponent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850169(v=vs.85).aspx) they are used to exchange the data through registry between Hyper-V host and Guest operating systems.

Is there any alternative to do the same for VirtualBox and VMware to read Guest registry from Host without any networking between them.

I can read the guest registry from host while using Hyper-V.